# Is there a simple way in python to parse Bloomberg API response to JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, blpapi

First, I'm talking about Bloomberg API (ie API used when you have a Bloomberg terminal, not web based stuff).

Bloomberg response is a headache in kind-of XML response. Is there a simple way to directly parse into JSON ? (from object 'session' or from object 'event')

```
HistoricalDataResponse = {
    securityData = {
        security = "S X5 Comdty"
        eidData[] = {
            14001, 14001
        }
        sequenceNumber = 1
        fieldExceptions[] = {
        }
        fieldData[] = {
            fieldData = {
                date = 2015-05-06
                PX_LAST = 956.0
                OPEN = 967.25
            }
            fieldData = {
                date = 2015-06-06
                PX_LAST = 914.25
                OPEN = 956.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the response. Since we have "=" instead of ":" in any json online viewer it gives error as a invalid json.

Comment: At least post a sample!

Comment: hum, Bloomberg API documentation is 350 pages, and session/service handling is well explained in it, no problem on that. But at one point you have a session object and a event object. A simple print() gives only : blpapi.session.Session object at #mem_addr. So no real sample to provide in fact.

Comment: already done, but their support for python API is non-existant. I also asked them twice to port API to python 3. "After confirmation it is not planned in the short term future". but it is out of subject...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can convert the XML response to a Python dict using something like [xmltodict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict).

Then convert the dict to JSON using `json.dumps()`.